# Setting a property specific to ear / war application in web logic

Tags: java, weblogic

I am deploying an ear file in web logic .
This ear file is a RMI client and uses some 3rd party jars .
These 3rd party jars need the following properties :

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
```

The problem with these properties is that these mess up weblogic admin console.
The console no longer is accessible once the above two properties get fired .

when I try to access weblogic console after these properties are set I get the following exception :

```
    <24/05/2019 5:23:34 PM EST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.io.IOException: Unable to create InitialContext: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
        at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.findRMIServer(ClientProvider.java:126)
        at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.newJMXConnector(ClientProvider.java:103)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:369)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.lookupMBeanServerConnection(MBeanUtils.java:3658)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.getDomainRuntimeMBeanServerConnection(MBeanUtils.java:1840)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtils.getDomainRuntimeServiceMBean(MBeanUtils.java:1916)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.initMBeanUtils(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:70)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer.access$000(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:20)
        at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitializer$1.run(MBeanUtilsInitializer.java:49)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.findRMIServer(ClientProvider.java:124)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
        ... 17 more
>
<24/05/2019 5:23:34 PM EST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: Error when initilize JMX connection>
<24/05/2019 5:23:37 PM EST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: java.io.IOException: Unable to create InitialContext: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
        at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.findRMIServer(ClientProvider.java:126)
        at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider.newJMXConnector(ClientProvider.java:103)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:369)
```

so clearly setting properties at System level is not a good idea and it is messing up web logic .

Since these properties are being used by 3rd party jars ( code which I cannot change ) how do I provide these properties to the jars without impacting web logic?

essentially these properties should be set specific to my application without interfering with web logic.

Comment: You can try to create a jndi.properties file inside your application (in a folder referenced by the classpath) and set these values.

Comment: Thanks but how do they become available to the 3rd party jar ? sorry I am not clear

Comment: if the jndi.properties file is in the application's classpath it will be read by the library.

Comment: so as simple as a a properties file like java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099 sounds interesting - will give it a try